# Replace part of filename with string in subdirectories and current directory

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

I want to be able to do this: rename `string1` to `string3` and add `string2` to the beginning. Sth like Fish renamed to Great_Bear if string Fish is found and Great_ = string2.

So far I have this:

```
    ls | sed s'/\(.*\)\(string1\)\(.*\)/mv \"&\" \"\1string3\" /' | bash
```

This does the job for current directory.

```
    ls -d $PWD/**/* | sed s'/\(.*\)\(string1\)\(.*\)/mv \"&\" \"\1string3\" /' | bash
```

This works only in subdirectories and not in the one where the script is.

Also I would like to know how to add `string2` to the beginning of the filename.

Comment: Can you add some example filenames and show how they should be renamed?

Comment: original filename "Bill_Jones.jpg" and renamed would be "renamed_Bill_Rody.jpg" for example

Comment: So in that example "Jones" would be "string1", "Rody" would be "string2" and "renamed" would be the string to append at the start, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is corrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/(.*)\/(.*)string1(.*)/$1\/string3$2string2$3/' {} +
```

- `find . -type f -exec`: searches recursively for files in the current working directory's hierarchy and executes the remainder of the command line expanding `{} +` to the list of results;
- `rename -n 's/(.*)\/(.*)string1(.*)/$1\/string3$2string2$3/' {} +`: matches and groups any number of any character until the last occurence of `/`, matches a `/`, matches and groups any number of any character until the last occurence of `string1`, matches `string1` and matches and groups any number of any character; replaces the match with the first captured group followed by a `/` character followed by `string3` followed by the second captured group followed by `string2` followed by the third captured group (`-n` makes `rename` perform a dry-run; remove it to actually rename the files).

```
% tree
.
└── dir
    ├── string1_bar.jpg
    ├── string1_foobar.jpg
    └── string1_foo.jpg

1 directory, 3 files
% find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/(.*)\/(.*)string1(.*)/$1\/string3$2string2$3/' {} +
rename(./dir/string1_foo.jpg, ./dir/string3string2_foo.jpg)
rename(./dir/string1_foobar.jpg, ./dir/string3string2_foobar.jpg)
rename(./dir/string1_bar.jpg, ./dir/string3string2_bar.jpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `rename` with a simple `*/*` match, not the globstar pattern..

```
rename 's|([^/]+)/(.+)|$1/$1_$2|' */* -vn
```

We're matching a directory and then something it contains. This is somewhat safer than the globstar because we don't want to recurse too far.

The `-n` on the end stops it actually *doing* anything. It'll just show you. Remove that when you're sure it's correct. Here's a little test harness though:

```
$ mkdir -p test/test{1..3} && touch test/test{1..3}/file{1..3}
$ cd test
$ rename 's|([^/]+)/(.+)|$1/$1_$2|' */* -vn
test1/file1 renamed as test1/test1_file1
test1/file2 renamed as test1/test1_file2
test1/file3 renamed as test1/test1_file3
test2/file1 renamed as test2/test2_file1
test2/file2 renamed as test2/test2_file2
test2/file3 renamed as test2/test2_file3
test3/file1 renamed as test3/test3_file1
test3/file2 renamed as test3/test3_file2
test3/file3 renamed as test3/test3_file3
```