# Rename files owned by user who runs the script

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this script that renames files specifically.

```
#!/bin/bash
#sh j
echo "for rename press [y]"
echo "Or any key to continue"
find . -name "*string1*" -ok rename -v -- 's/(.*)\/(.*)string1(.*)/$1\/beginning_$2string3$3/' {} \;
echo "No more matches."
```

Now I want to rename only files that are owned by the user who runs the script.

Comment: I don't really know bash, but I believe it should be done in a conditional (if) statement. So, if fileOwnership == ``whoami`` then rename. Logic of that degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That `find` command looks familiar...](https://askubuntu.com/a/702275/380067)

To narrow down the `find` command only to files owned only by a certain user, you can use the `-user` switch; to narrow it down only to files owned by the user running the script (i.e. e.g. if you're running the script using `sudo` only files owned by root will be matched), pass `$USER` as the argument to the `-user` switch:

```
find . -name "*string1*" -user "$USER" -ok rename -v -- 's/(.*)\/(.*)string1(.*)/$1\/beginning_$2string3$3/' {} \;
```

You could replace `{} \;` with `{} +` for a better performance:

```
find . -name "*string1*" -user "$USER" -ok rename -v -- 's/(.*)\/(.*)string1(.*)/$1\/beginning_$2string3$3/' {} +
```

Comment: Is there a difference between -user "$(whoami)" and -user "$USER" ?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I got confused myself, I made my mind up a bit. It depends. Inside of your script no, because the real user and the effective user running the command are the same: `$(whoami)` will return the effective user, and `$USER` will return `$USER` as set by the shell (which is set to the effective user running the shell). So since it doesn't make a difference in this case use `$USER`, since `$(whoami)` forks a subshell and a process, while `$USER` is simply read from the environment.